# Value is not edited. Cucumber + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I have an assigment to make simple BDD test.

I have scenario like this:

```
Background: movies in database
 
  Given the following movies exist:
  | title        | rating | director     | release_date |
  | Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
  | Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
  | Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
  | THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |
 
Scenario: add director to existing movie
  When I go to the edit page for "Alien"
  And  I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"
  And  I press "Update Movie Info"
  Then the director of "Alien" should be "Ridley Scott
```

I have steps like this:

```
When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end

When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end

When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end

Then /^the director of "([^"]*)" should be "([^"]*)"$/ do |movie, director|
    film = Movie.find_by_title(movie)
    puts page.body
    assert film.director.should == director
end
```

My problem is that the director value is not editing. And I can`t compare it to director.

Others values are assigned correctly, I can for example assert "film.rating.should == director" And get that expected "Ridley Scott" got "R". But for the director I got nil.

It is not the problem with view for which I have created field for edit a director or db where I have a dirctor column.

My intuition is that db is not reloaded but I couldn`t find a command for this.

I will be glad for any help :)

**Answer:**

I forgot to include :director in my model, and it wasn`t able to retrive the argument. Thnx for any help since I learned from it any way.

Comment: have you migrated the DB for the `test` environment, exaclty for `cucumber` environment?

Comment: I used rake db:test:prepared and it still not passing the edited value

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` is you are using test db named `test`

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right, I don't know how exactly to reload the database either however what I would say is that because your writing an integration test just focus on how the user see's the site.

If you gave your test a few more steps like navigating to the "Alien" movie page and checking to see if the director shown on the page is "Ridley Scott" you would know that the director has been changed in your database but also that it is being displayed in your view (something that is not checked by checking the database directly).

[Rspec expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations) is great for checking page content.

eg

`expect(page).to have_text("Director: #{director})`

Comment: The blame was on my side, by the way your answer was also correct when I push director arrgument to attr_accessor